# Firebase problem "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, vite

I'm trying to create a new document when a user signs up for my app.

However, 'exports' is returning "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: exports is not defined".

The code below is handling the function. I do also have an onAuthStateChanged function that switches some logged-in/out elements, although I don't think that could be stopping exports from being defined.

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, 
signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { db, auth } from "./firebase";
import { collection, doc, setDoc, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const signUpForm = document.querySelector('#signup-form');
if (signUpForm) {
    signUpForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //get user info
        const email = signUpForm['signup-email'].value;
        const password = signUpForm['signup-password'].value;

        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((cred) => {
            const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
            overlay.classList.add('hidden');
            overlayP.classList.remove('hidden');
            signUpForm.reset();
            exports.createUserDoc = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
                return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).setDoc({ 
                    email: user.email,
                    uid: user.uid,
                })
            });
            // document.getElementById("signUpErr").innerHTML = "";
        })
        // .catch(err => {
            // document.getElementById("signUpErr").innerHTML = err.message;
        // });
    });
};
```

I have initialized firebase and installed express.js within my index.js file but am I missing something to make sure this parameter is defined? I'm using Vite as a package bundler and node.js.

I'm new to coding and firebase, any advice would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your `functions.js` file with the exception of the other functions?

Comment: @fakegirlfriends I have updated the post to include more of the function.js file. I'm wondering whether it's because I haven't imported the index.js file. If it is, the index.js file does not provide an export named 'exports'. How might I phrase this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `index.js` file. When you created this project on your local machine, did you opt to use TypeScript instead of JavaScript?

Comment: @fakegirlfriends I did use Javascript on setup. I have managed to solve my problem which was down to ignorance and trying to use a cloud function in my app.js file. Thanks for taking the time to read my question, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by taking a few days to read the documentation and understand what is going on with Cloud functions. The benefit of having a cloud function is that you can create triggers to your database that is away from your client-side code, improving security.

I was trying to call the cloud function within my app.js file and not within the firestore functions index.js file created when initializing firebase. Here you import through CommonJS Modules (CJS) the required SDK, in my case it was functions and admin.

Now my cloud functions live within index.js in /Functions folder separate from my app files.

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and set up triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

I also had to change the .setDoc() function to .set() as this was a Type error. I also added a userDelete function to delete users' documents in firestore.

```
exports.createUserDoc = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    // Your new auth record will have the uid and email on it because
    // you used email as the way to create the auth record
    return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
        email: user.email,
        bookmarked: []
    })
});

exports.userDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete(user => {
    const doc = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid);
    return doc.delete();
});
```

I would also like to note that setting up the firestore emulator has been very useful in this process and I'm sure will help me develop and test the other functions I need to create my app.